# FTP Download speeds limited

Tags: wireless-networking, ftp, sftp

I have two PC's on the same network. One via WiFi and one via LAN connecting to the same FTP server to download files. The network is a 400mbps connection. Both are Windows 10 Pro PC's.

For some reason the one via WiFi is limited to 4mbps per connection. Meaning that I can have 10 of these running at the same time, using 40mbps of my bandwidth (4mbps per) or just 1 running and it only run at 4mbps. I can hit about 350mbps consistently using different applications that dont use the FTP protocol such as Steam or direct download via Chrome.

The PC that is connected via lan is not limited at all on a per connection basis. I can download one file at about 240mbps or I can download 10 files at my full bandwidth 400mbps.

For the PC on WiFi, this happens regardless of the application, it is limited to that 500kbps per connection if it is using the FTP protocol.

Are there any settings that might be causing this?

Windows firewall is completely off
Windows defender is completely off
I tried to open ports but it made no difference.
Tried both FTP and SFTP

Comment: Which FTP client are you using?

Comment: I have tried to download through chrome, filezilla (which is what I use on both computers with the exact same settings) and netdrive.  All are limited to 500kbps on the PC with WiFi.

Comment: Does the affected PC go faster when connected by ethernet?

Comment: Tested it on a Ethernet, same exact speeds, no change.